# Python. AttributeError when setting parent's property from overwritten property

Tags: python, overwrite

I'm trying to overwrite a third-party's Button class property, but i'm facing a weird problem to me.

Here is the code to overwrite the "Pressed" property

```
class Button(Button):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()        

    @property
    def Pressed(self):
        print("Do something")        
        return super(Button,self).Pressed

    @Pressed.setter
    def Pressed(self,func):
        print("Pressed property {}".format(super(Button,self).Pressed))
        print(hasattr(super(Button,self),"Pressed"))
        setattr(super(Button,self),'Pressed',func)
```

When the "setter" is called it prints:

- Pressed property None
- True
- And then throws AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'Pressed'

But if i checked at the previous line of code if it has the attribute and it returned "True", how is it possible to throw an error at the very next line saying that there is not attribe "Pressed"????

I'v also tryied `super(Button,self) = func` but with the same result.

PS: I have no access to the Button superclass code.

Comment: Why does the name of your class coincide with the name of the base class?

Comment: @MorgoZ have you tried monkey patching ?

Comment: @Leon it is to overwrite Button class. If i'd use a different name i'd been creating a child class.

Comment: Your question will receive more attention (and upvotes) if you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I was able to reproduce the problem with an MCVE created on my own, but not everyone will invest that much effort.